# how can I partially initialize a 3D array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

I need to initialise a 3 level array, I know the size of the 2 first levels but the last one is determined randomly and varies from array to array.

```
int[,,] myArray;
```

How can I initialise the 2 first levels yet leave the last one untouched ?

```
myArray = new int[sizeA, sizeB, ???];
```

Comment: I'd preferably use an array as I do not need to resize the 3D array at all and I always ways the 3 ( valid ) keys to access a value. Using a 3D array rather than a 3D list makes more sense to me for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E.g., array 3 x 5 x Variable_size:

```
        int[][][] myArray = new int[3][][];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            myArray[i] = new int[5][];

        myArray[0][0] = new int[5];
        myArray[0][1] = new int[6];
        myArray[0][2] = new int[3];
        myArray[0][3] = new int[2];
        myArray[0][4] = new int[7];
        myArray[1][0] = new int[3];
        //...
        myArray[2][4] = new int[9];
```

or

```
        int[,][] myArray = new int[3,5][];
        myArray[0, 0] = new int[3];
        myArray[0, 1] = new int[5];
        myArray[0, 2] = new int[2];
        myArray[0, 3] = new int[4];
        myArray[0, 4] = new int[6];
        myArray[1, 0] = new int[3];
        //...
        myArray[2, 4] = new int[8];
```

Usage accordingly:

```
myArray[0][1][3] = 5;
int a = myArray[1][0][2];
```

or

```
myArray[0, 1][3] = 5;
int a = myArray[1, 0][2];
```